# tried to update from lucid lynx, now computer won't boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, 10.10, partial-upgrade

I  don't know much about my computer, I  have been trying to get an old custom computer updated.  it was running on lucid lynx, I  tried to update from the terminal  with  some 'copy and pasted' 'sudo  get  upgrade',  I'm not sure what exactly I put in the terminal but it looked like it was doing its thing,  then it got hung up somewhere and I  mistakenly tried to resart.  now when I turn the computer on  it goes  to the 'ubuntu'  loading screen  but never completely boots.  I'm sad, and have no idea what to do, and am way beyond my understanding.... please help

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be exactly what you are looking for but since your level of experience as you say is low I would suggest you do the following:

First, boot-up your system using a liveCD or liveUSB and make a complete backup of your home folder to some external media.

Second, do a completely new install on your system. Of course, this will **wipe out all data** on your hard disk.

Last, restore your backed-up home folder to the new installation. You might have to perform this step while booted from a liveCD/USB to avoid overwriting open system files on your home folder.

These procedure will at least give you a working system as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

hmayag's answer will get you up and running again, but if I were you I'd switch to Lubuntu 13.04 rather than running that old ****box version of Ubuntu. ;OP

Unless you require the older operating system for running certain programs or drivers that aren't compatible with later versions of Ubuntu, personally I'd want to try and get an up to date OS.
In that case you'll still want to do the /home folder thing so that you've got a backup should you want to return to Lucid Lynx, but when copying files back into the home folder of 13.04, it'd be best to only copy the folders such as documents pictures videos Desktop etc, as those folders don't contain any program settings, just your documents.
That way you'll have a clean slate of settings for the new Ubuntu version, as the ones from a really old Ubuntu may stuff things up on the new Ubuntu version.

You can get Lubuntu here:
http://lubuntu.net/

It's a cut down version of the current release of Ubuntu designed for older computers. As the full Ubuntu 13.04 requires more of the hardware than many old PC's can deal with.