# Ubuntu cannot start after upgrade 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

Yesterday I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10. After restart with Ubuntu 12.10 launcher and top menu weren't shown. So I tried to solve this problem. When I googled this problem I found a solution in ask ubuntu form. I did that solution which link is in below:
[Ubuntu 12.10 shows no launcher or menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208346/ubuntu-12-10-shows-no-launcher-or-menu)

I followed the solition in step one. After I did this I restart my computer and now Ubuntu cannot launch.

These errors are given:

```
sck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda5: clean 292675/14319616 files, 5132792/57276672 blocks
The disk drive for media/Elements is not ready yet or not present 
keys: Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Spqwing maintenance shell

After Pressing M this error is given:

```
Filesystem check ot mount failed
A maintenance shell will now be started

Control-D will terminate this shell  and continue booting after re-trying filesystem Any futher errors will be ignored

mountall start starting
```

then system locked.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe a `dup()` from 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/291813/tried-to-update-from-lucid-lynx-now-computer-wont-boot

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to make a fresh install for new versions of OSes. I would suggest you take backup of your files, format the disk and do a clean install of 12.10. It takes very less time to do clean install then the time it takes to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10.